# How to limit login only for 5 devices in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I am working on an Api for login and logout (Spring boot).

There is requirement that an user is allowed to login only in 5 devices.

How i can implement this using spring boot?

Comment: Do you want to restrict concurrent logins?

Comment: How about using a caching mechanism like redis or something which will store logged in user details centrally?

Comment: Do you want same user login for only 5 different device ?

Comment: i want same user login for only 5 different devices @MeetPatel

Comment: no i don't want to strict concurrent logins. i just want to restrict same user login to 5 different devices.@DurlabhSharma

Comment: What counts as a separate device? Browsers? Incognito sessions?

Comment: i am working on the back-end of an mobile application here device indicates-(Android device and IOS device)  @chrylis-onstrike-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of device if you allow only 5 registered device to be able login than you have to maintain it in database.

But if you want any at most 5 device able to login at same time than try this - https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/spring-security.html#spring-security-concurrent-sessions

use `maximumSessions(5)`

```
http
    // other config goes here...
    .sessionManagement()
                    .maximumSessions(5)
```

This will allow only 5 session at a time for same user

Comment: i am storing device id in database.But then how will i logout a user only from a single device when user will hit the logout api.and he should be logged-in on the other devices. @MeetPatel

Comment: logout has nothing to do device id. it binds with session only. once user will hit logout api from any device that session is going to invalid for that device. it will not effect other devices